# Multiple Tag Fields on One Model in Django, or ManyToMany Fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-tagging

I have a `Book` model that needs two separate Tag fields: `genre` and `tags`. I'm considering whether it would be better to write my own `Genre` and `BookTag` models for this, and linking it with `ManyToManyField`s or using DjangoTagging to achieve the same.

Ultimately, I need users to be able to filter either according to `genre`, or according to `tag`, but I don't need the Tag Cloud functionality.

From what I can see, Django Tagging allows two `TagField`s, but then it casts both into the same tag cloud. That's not a problem for me, but before I start refactoring all my code to use Django Tagging instead of my own ManyToMany fields, are there any other catches of using Django Tagging in this situation that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Negatives**

- Django tag fields don't have slug fields so you will manually have to slugify the tag.name if you want to use them in Urls
- You can't (without subclassing django-taggings models) add any other fields to a genre or book tag so you won't easily be able to describe the genre or tag.
- Regarding useability: If you are using django-tagging you will more then likely be using a TagField to enter the tags (be them genres or booktags). The problem with this is that you need to remember exactly what tags you have used before, as opposed to a foreignkey or manytomanyfield where you are selecting from a list.

**Positives**

- Django tagging has a nice API for querying tags and tagged items

---

[django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) is another tagging application that is widely used and still developed and overcomes some of the above limitations

Comment: Thanks, very useful! I see your point with the usability thing, but I think that becomes a positive when you have thousands of tags, and you combine it with an AJAX suggestion script. 

Not having slug fields automatically sucks, but not too hard to fix. 

As for django-taggit, what are the relative advantages?

Comment: It has slug fields and it's extensible so you can overcome problems such as point 2 https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/docs/custom_tagging.txt

Comment: Django Taggit it will be, particularly because of the extensibility of using your own Tag model - looks like a perfect fit! Thanks!

Comment: I've also convinced myself to switch over I think!